# R: Add values to waterfall chart

Tags: r, plot, lattice, waterfall

I am using the [waterfall package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/waterfall/index.html) in R to prepare waterfall charts and like to add the values to the chart.

Example code (taken from http://lamages.blogspot.de/2012/05/waterfall-charts-in-style-of-economist.html):

```
library(latticeExtra)
library(waterfall)
data(rasiel) # Example data of the waterfall package
rasiel
#    label          value   subtotal
# 1  Net Sales       150    EBIT
# 2  Expenses       -170    EBIT 
# 3  Interest         18    Net Income
# 4  Gains            10    Net Income
# 5  Taxes            -2    Net Income

asTheEconomist(
               waterfallchart(value~label, data=rasiel,
                              groups=subtotal, main="P&L")
               )
```

Results in this plot:

[image: Plot from example]

I am looking for the correct code to get something like this:

[image: Plot modified]

Comment: About 3/4 of the way down the page they show you how to do that in ggplot: http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/ggplot2-waterfall-charts/. Someone else will have to comment on the waterfall package, I've never used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

waterfallchart simply uses the lattice package with specific settings to create this type of plot. Consequently, all of the lattice functions that modify plots will work inside of waterfallchart.

You have to set the text parameters of the panel like so:

```
asTheEconomist(
  waterfallchart(value~label, data=rasiel,
                      groups=subtotal, main="P&L",
                 panel=function(x, y, ...) {
                   panel.waterfallchart(x, y, ...);
                   ltext(x=seq(1,7,1),y=c(75,75,10,1,20,15,14),
                         labels=c("+150","-170","-20","+10","+18","-2","+6"),
                         srt=90,font=2,cex=1.5)
                 }
       )
)
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to automize the labelling rather than doing it manually as proposed.

Comment: The y-coordinate you have to do manually. As for the labels, some massaging is still required, as -20 and +6 are not in the rasiel$value.

Comment: With your own data, all you have to do is stick whatever variable you want for your labels in there. With this data though you can't because of the two additional bars. You either have to do it manually or write even more lines to make it somewhat programmatic.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, this is not possible.  When I wrote the code for waterfallplot and waterfallchart, I explicitly tried to mimic the behavior of barplot and barchart, respectively.  At the time, and this was some years ago, neither had an option to support this and I don't think that's changed.

I think more progress would be made by reimplementing waterfall plots in ggplot2, and it should make this and other plot tweaks relatively easy.

Comment: But then how come I was able to do it (see my answer)?

Although I agree that ggplot2 is almost always the better plotting option.

Comment: It's not possible using the software as is.   You can wrap it and make it do anything you want.